# Set value to checkbox & retrieve that value in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I want to display all userroles in my company access, however i can do this and at the same time the selected userroleid has to be retrieved from form so as to save in database.

In View:

I have multiple check boxes with userroles and every user role is having an id. On checking the particular checkbox, that userrole id has to retreived . Any suggestions please??

My code in view is like this:-

```
@foreach (var r in @Model.RolesList)
{
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model1 => Model.UserRole) @r.RoleName
}
```

So i want to retrieve the selected checkbox userroleid .How to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled a similar situation once

What you can do it that you can use for loop and use a hidden element to get Ids in form POST Action

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.RolesList.Count; i++)
{
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(o => o.RolesList[i].UserRole.Checked)//checked is a bit that represents selected/unselected
   @Html.Label(Model.RolesList[i].UserRole.Name)
   @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.RolesList[i].UserRole.ID)
}
```

In form post, when you bind your form with List of `RolesList` you'll get a  `UserRole` which will have the Id of `UserRole` and checked bit to represent if it is selected or unselected

In my case, `UserRole` is not bool but the following

```
public class UserRole
{
   public long Id{set;get;}
   public String Name {set; get;}
   Public bool Checked {set;get;}
}
```

But since you cannot change your `UserRole` from `bool` to what I suggested, you can try the following

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.RolesList.Count; i++)
{
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(o => o.RolesList[i])
   @Html.Label(Model.RolesList[i].Name) // what ever you want to display in the label
   @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.RolesList[i].ID) // Id to uniquely identify each Role in RoleList
}
```

Comment: But it doesn't work at all. How an array i.e [i] can be applied to bool type variable i mean "UserRole" checkbox property datatype must be bool right???? In my model class, data type of UserRole is bool which can't be changed right!!!!

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't properly understand the requirements. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry for my comment its working. I forgot to convert my UserRole property to bool list.Thanks...!!!!!!!

Comment: Yeah..... that's right... !!!!!!the code you provided second time is exactly what i have done in my application.

Comment: I have one more doubt.If the user checks more than one check box how to get those values in controller???

Comment: I have one more doubt, how to get that value in the controller? Also if the user checks the multiple check buttons, how to get those values in the controller??

Comment: I got the entire solution for my requirement. Thanks for your co-operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var r in @Model.RolesList)
                 {
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model1 => r.UserRole) @r.RoleName<br />
                 }
```

Comment: No need of sorry man....!!!! i am just asking what u answered ..nothing more than that..take it is easy:)

Comment: yeah.. hehe
i'm newbie in MVC... and i try to learn, if i make some mistake, hehe i,m so sorry about this.